# Jquery smoothwheel.js in a Chrome extension to smooth scroll every scrollable web page

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, smooth-scrolling

is it possible to change how Chrome scrolls the web pages like "smoothwheel.js" does? I want to create a Chrome extension that allows me to do that, but I'm not sure how I could achieve it.

https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/jquery.smoothwheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to change how Chrome scrolls. There are several extensions that already exist:

Smooth Key Scroll: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smooth-key-scroll/gphmhpfbknciemgfnfhjapilmcaecljh

Smooth Scroll: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smoothscroll/nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj

The extensions achieve this by hijacking the `keydown, keyup, wheel` events and throttling and smoothing the scroll through `requestAnimationFrame` or similar.